# Cross compiling error in python code converted in c code for raspberry pi target machine in Ubuntu Virtual machine

Tags: python, c, ubuntu

I have to compile python code into *executable*. To do that on my RPi3 b+ I use cython to convert *.py* into *.c* code and then using gcc to create an executable file. The compiling process is very slow but it works. I would like to cross compile from an other machine. I have Ubuntu Virtual machine and I followed this tutorial:  https://www.diprimio.com/techies/howto/72/come-fare-cross-compile-per-raspberry-pi-con-ubuntu.

The compiling process success when compiling pure *.c* code (such the classical hello world), however it fail when have to include python libraries. When I execute `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o test test.c` it fails and reports *Python.h not found*. 
Including the python path (which was already installed such as python-dev and python3-dev) with:
`$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I/usr/include/python3.5 -o test test.c` 
it fails and reports `pyconfig.h: No such file or directory` error.

Could someone help me? I accept also additional solutions of cross compiling.